# How To Optimise This Cython Function?

Tags: python, cython, numba

I have a Cython module:

```
#!python
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, nonecheck=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def portfolio_s2( double[:,:] cv, double[:] weights ):    
    """ Calculate portfolio variance"""
    cdef double s0
    cdef double s1
    cdef double s2
    s0 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0] ):
        s0 += weights[i]*weights[i]*cv[i,i]

    s1 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0]-1 ):
        s2 = 0.0
        for j in range( i+1, weights.shape[0] ):
            s2 += weights[j]*cv[i,j]
        s1+= weights[i]*s2
    return s0+2.0*s1
```

I have the equivalent function in Numba:

```
@nb.jit( nopython=True )
def portfolio_s2( cv, weights ):
    """ Calculate portfolio variance using numba """
    s0 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0] ):
        s0 += weights[i]*weights[i]*cv[i,i]

    s1 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0]-1 ):
        s2 = 0.0
        for j in range( i+1, weights.shape[0] ):
            s2 += weights[j]*cv[i,j]
        s1+= weights[i]*s2
    return s0+2.0*s1
```

For a covariance matrix of size 10, the Numba version is 20 times faster than Cython. I assume that this is due to something I am doing wrong in Cython, but I am new to Cython and am not sure what to do.

Using Cel's Optimisation...

I have written a script to test Cel's code vs the Numba version:

```
    sizes = [ 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 196, 256 ]
    cython_timings = []
    numba_timings = []
    for size in sizes:
        X = np.random.randn(100,size)
        cv = np.cov( X, rowvar=0 )
        w  = np.ones( cv.shape[0] )

        num_tests=10

        pm.portfolio_s2( cv, w )
        with Timer( 'Cython' ) as cython_timer:
            for _ in range( num_tests ):
                s2_cython = pm.portfolio_s2_opt( cv, w )
        cython_timings.append( cython_timer.interval )

        helpers.portfolio_s2( cv, w )
        with Timer( 'Numba' ) as numba_timer:
            for _ in range( num_tests ):
                s2_numba = helpers.portfolio_s2( cv, w )
        numba_timings.append( numba_timer.interval )

    plt.plot( sizes, cython_timings, label='Cython' )
    plt.plot( sizes, numba_timings, label='Numba' )
    plt.title( 'Execution Time By Covariance Size' )
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

The resulting chart looks like this:

[image]

The chart shows that for small covariance matrices, Numba performs better. But as the covariance matrix size increases, Cython scales better and eventually outperforms by a large margin.

Is there some sort of function call overhead that is causing Cython to have such poor performance for small matrices? My use case for this code will involve calculating covariances for lots of small covariance matrices. So I need better performance for small matrices rather than large.

Comment: There is a good tutorial in the [cython docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html). Also remember to declare the types of every single variable. Note that `i` is not statically typed.

Comment: if the performance of cython is "poor" then why don't you stick to numba?

Comment: Numba does not let me create arrays in nopython mode. So I am learning Cython.

Comment: Your test may well be  bit misleading: you're meauring the python->cython (or python->numba) call overhead. If you 'cpdef' the function and call it from within Cython it could be better.

Comment: Is the calling overhead significant for your problem? If that's the case you can avoid that function call by `cythonizing` more of your code and not using a function at all. Note, that you are trading the nice structure of your program for speed. I would only do this if you really need this extra speed.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing when using `Cython` is to make sure that everything is statically typed.

In your example the loop variables `i` and `j` were not typed. The declaration `cdef size_t i, j` already gives you a massive speedup.

There are nice examples in the [`Working with NumPy`](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) section of `cython`'s docs.

This is my setup and the evaluation:

```
import numpy as np
n = 100
cv = np.random.rand(n,n)
weights= np.random.rand(n)
```

The original version:

```
%timeit portfolio_s2(cv, weights)
10000 loops, best of 3: 147 µs per loop
```

The optimized version:

```
%timeit portfolio_s2_opt(cv, weights)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10 µs per loop
```

And here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


def portfolio_s2_opt(double[:,:] cv, double[:] weights):    
    """ Calculate portfolio variance"""
    cdef double s0
    cdef double s1
    cdef double s2
    cdef size_t i, j

    s0 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0] ):
        s0 += weights[i]*weights[i]*cv[i,i]

    s1 = 0.0
    for i in range( weights.shape[0]-1 ):
        s2 = 0.0
        for j in range( i+1, weights.shape[0] ):
            s2 += weights[j]*cv[i,j]
        s1+= weights[i]*s2
    return s0+2.0*s1
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the big gains come from typing `i` and `j` (Cython even warns me when I don't do that). Using the numpy interface rather than the `double [:]` memoryview interface like in the original code gives me ~2% speed-up.

Comment: @DavidW, using `Memoryviews` does not give me a speedup. However they seem to be preferred now. I am going to revise my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.